# Первая JVM для платформы Java SE

Tags: java, jvm, интерпретатор, hotspot

Собственно говоря, сам вопрос кроется в залоговке данной темы. Знаю, что примерно с 2002 года освной реализацией JVM для платформы Java SE является всем известный канонический «HotSpot», изначально разработанный компанией «Longview Technologies», которая затем была поглащена Sun Microsystems. На тот момент времени, вышеуказанная JVM создавалась для версии 1.3 платформы Java SE.

А что было раньше? Какая именно JVM использовалась в самых ранних версиях? Официальной датой релиза самого языка принято считать 23-е мая 1995-го года. Какая же JVM была наиболее популярна в 1995-1996 годах и вплоть до появления «HotSpot»? Пытался найти данную информацию в глобальной сети, но ничего не получилось. Также, если позволите, хотелось бы узнать, на каком языке программирования написано большинство JVM и есть ли какая-нибудь JVM, которая была написана на чистой Java'е (также интересует ЯП на котором была написана первая JVM). Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: JVM на java точно не было, последнее время есть подвижки в этом направлении, например graalvm,  но он не на 100 процентов написан на java.

Comment: JVM — это экземпляр JRE - этот экземпляр удаляется сборщиком мусора. JIT. Только не понятно, зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: @Artem Konovalov Интересно получается. А какие ещё языки программирования использовались при написании GraalVM? И можно было бы чисто теоретически написать JVM с нуля исключительно на языке программирования Java? Если же нет, то по какой причине?

Comment: @And В смысле? Не понял Вас... Какой ещё экземпляр? Речь идёт о виртуальной машине. Сборщик мусора является частью JVM. Как сборщик мусора может "удалить" JVM?

Comment: исходники открыты, можно посмотреть статистику на github https://github.com/oracle/graal

Comment: Да и кстати, термин Java SE появился только начиная с версии 1.4 по-моему. До этого был просто Java, потом начиная с версии 1.3 пошла Java EE и только с 1.4 официально разделили на 2 части SE и EE

Comment: @Barmaley Благодарю Вас за полезную информацию! Я так понимаю, что изначально Java являлась единой платформой и для неё существовала единая JVM. Кстати говоря, пока не очень знаком с платформой Java EE, но насколько я понимаю, то для запуска программ написанных под этой платформой может подойти и обычная JVM, которая изначально предназначена для Java SE. Верно?

Comment: @Artem Konovalov Благодарю Вас за исходники!

Comment: @Lexoid ну да сейчас в комплект поставки входят 2 версии JVM клиентская и серверная.

Comment: @Barmaley Вы имеете в виду Java EE и Java SE? Но ведь есть ещё Java ME и Java Card... Или же я не совсем правильно Вас понял?

Comment: Ну если и дальше копаться, то была (упс еще жива) KVM - kilobyte VM - для платформы J2ME (mobile edition)

Comment: @Barmaley В общем, Вы просто имели в виду JVM для Java SE и Java EE? То есть, для Java SE используется в основном «HotSpot». А для Java EE какая?

Comment: @Lexoid клиентская и серверная JVM - это не Java SE и Java EE. Это конфигурации HotSpot оптимизированные под разные сценарии работы. А SE и EE - это условно разделённые наборы стандартов.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Вот теперь понял, огромное спссибо!

Comment: Вам следует прочитать об этом [подробнее](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine)

Comment: @And Я читал эту статью. JVM является средой исполнения для Java-приложений (если говорить более обобщённо, то и программы написанные на других языках программирования также могут исполняться при помощи JVM). JRE является минимальный реализацией для JVM, которая кроме самой виртуальной машины содержит ещё и библиотеки Java-классов. Как сборщик мусора может удалить виртуальную машину, частью которой он сам и является? Да и вообще, как можно в принципе удалить виртуальную машину? Разве такое возможно?

Comment: Плохо читали, еще раз прочитайте, от начала и до конца.

Comment: Добавлю для разнообразия, что были попытки реализовать JVM в железе - [Java processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor), ну чтобы процессор сразу исполнял инструкции байткодов JVM, но все умерло как только появился JIT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сохранившиеся оригинальные сановские версии JDK/JRE/JVM можно [скачать здесь](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase11-419415.html) - это версия 1.1, более ранние версии увы не сохранились...

HotSpot пошел с версии JDK 1.2, до этого они просто назывались Sun JVM, потом когда Sun начал направо-налево лицензировать разные инкарнации JVM появилась необходимость отделить ее от остальных JVM.

Наиболее известная альтернативная инкарнация JVM была [JRockit](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRockit), которую вовсю понужал Bea Systems на своем сервере WebLogic - она вышла по-моему 1998 году - как то так и была настолько хороша, что было модно говорить, что Sun JVM скоро умрет :)

Я еще помню версии JVM 0.8/0.9, но уже в 2004 году [я их не мог найти](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1690295)

Почти все JVM пишутся на смеси C/Java

Comment: Короче, у компании «Sun Microsystems» была своя стандартная безымянная JVM, которую в программистской среде просто именовали Sun JVM. Я правильно Вас понял? А «HotSpot» уже получил своё всем известное имя, чтобы реализовации JVM было проще различать? Как-то так? Или не совсем верно?

Comment: Да, примерно так

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснения!)

Answer (score 2):

JVM HotSpot впервые стала использоваться в Java 1.2 в 1999-м. Судя по всему, у предыдущей виртуальной машины Sun просто не было названия. JVM по имени JVM. Подозреваю, что имя потребовалось тогда, когда Microsoft сделал свою виртуальную машину, с нарушениями JLS и JIT-компилятором.

Большинство JVM написаны на C. На Java написана GraalVM.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что данная JVM (GraalVM) ещё не вышла и находится на этапе разработки? И использовались ли ещё какие-либо языки программирования для написания этой JVM?

Comment: Нет, релиз был в апреле этого года. Но в данный момент это академическая разработка, для исследовательской деятельности в области виртуальных машин и компиляторов, из которой части постепенно переезжают в OpenJDK, а оттуда в другие реализации платформы Java. В частности в Java 10 на Linux'ах уже можно использовать компилятор Graal. К своему стыду я так и не нашёл времени ознакомиться с граалем поближе, поэтому точно не знаю, что у него там внутри. Подозреваю, что Artem Konovalov прав, и там хватает Сишного кода.

Comment: Скорее всего так и есть. Просто было интересно узнать, есть ли какая-нибудь JVM, которая была бы написана на языке программирования Java. Я так понимаю, что GraalVM единственная в своём роде JVM? Есть ли ещё какие-нибудь JVM, которые написаны на языке программирования Java?

Comment: Не могу точно сказать. Теоретически можно написать JVM на чистой Java, но производительность её оставить желать лучшего.

Comment: Интересная ситуация получается, если немного призадуматься. А каким образом будет обрабатываться весь Java-код такой JVM? При помощи другой JVM?! %)

Comment: Можно так. А можно Java-код такой JVM JIT-компилировать и обрабатывать уже нативные инструкции процессора.

Comment: Теперь я понимаю по какой причине почти все JVM пишутся на компилируемых языках. Как-то мудрёно получается с этой JIT-компиляцией. Думаю, что так никто не стал бы делать, хотя могу и ошибаться. Короче говоря, C наше всё!))